# Summer Note Issue: Insert Link dialog also hiding summer note dialog box

Tags: bootstrap-modal, summernote

I am using summer note for texteditor in my project. My editory is showing in bootstrap dialog box. Everything is working fine. But when I try to insert link, summernote open one more dialog box where it asks for link information. After providing all information, either I click on insert button or close icon of this link dialof box, summer note is also removing parent dialog box in which summer note is showing but backdrop overlay still remain same.

I am also attaching the screenshot of this issue below.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Can some please share how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem by adding **dialogsInBody** when initializing summernote. Example:

```
$('#your-modal').summernote({
    dialogsInBody: true
});
```